# How to store retrieved data from API locally and update those data at equal interval using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, api

I am building a webpage using web-services in Java Script. Currently, I have implemented the API and it displays the data on webpage. But, many time due to server failure data is not received and web page becomes empty.

So, I want to fetch data from API and store it locally and update those data at equal time interval. So, my application can always use locally stored data and web page never becomes empty.

How to do that, please share your views.?

Comment: You can store it in LocalStorage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you want to store data locally every time you fetch from API, so when you open the page next time, it will display last fetched data.

In that case, [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Client-side_storage) can be used. However, local storage should not be used for sensitive data and advanced objects. Also, it's stored as string data (JSON), so that also has some limitations.

Comment: Or sessionStorage could be an option to remove the data if the tab is closed

Comment: @OscarR sure, both extend Storage, so it really depends on the exact scenario. If he has requests polling every min, which some times updates with empty data values etc. sessionStorage might be a better approach.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into [Service Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API). This is one of the main technologies for creating an offline-enabled website. The rest of your code stays the same, but a service worker helps the browser to manage requests and caching behaviors. There are also higher-level libraries that could help make this easier, like [Workbox](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/) - a library from Google that "bakes in a set of best practices and removes the boilerplate every developer writes when working with service workers."